# Multiply two numbers with assembly

Tags: assembly

I need to build assembly code that return c = a * B.
With orders:

1. INC - Raising the value stored in one register.
2. DIC - Reducing the value stored in one register.
3. JNZ -Jump to a point in the code (LABEL). As long as the last
   operation was done near the line of code is not equal to zero.
4. HALT - Stopping the code.

You can use several registers want (less preferable)
and values all registers initialized to zero.

So,  I try to do this but unfortunately I get stuck.

// check that A || b  != 0 .

```
INC a 
DEC a 
Jnz Label 1
HALT .

Label 1
INC b
DEC b
Jnz Label 2 
HALT .
```

.....

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see how to do it without using a fourth register. I skip the test of either `a` or `b` is `0` because you have shown how you do that.

I want two nested loops so that `c` is incremented `a` x `b` times. The problem is remembering what the inner loop `b` was for next time, and that is the purpose of the fourth register. Written in C so I can easily test it.

Multiply `3` x `5` so that `c = a * b`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a=3, b=5, c=0, d=0;
    do {                    // outer loop a         label1:

        do {                // inner loop b
            c++;            // accumulate product c         INC c
            d++;            // remembering b                INC d
            b--;            // next inner loop b            DIC b
        } while(b != 0);    //                              JNZ label1

        do {                // inner loop d         label2:
            b++;            // restoring b                  INC b
            d--;            // next inner loop d            DIC d
        } while(d != 0);    //                              JNZ label2

        a--;                // next outer loop a            DIC a
    } while(a != 0);        //                              JNZ label1
                            //                              HALT
    printf("%d", c);
    return c;
}
```

Program output

```
15
```

As you can see this can be implemented with the four instructions you may use.

Comment: Then please as a new question, thank you. I have answered the question that was asked.